# How to make objects appear when I want to see without clicking 'Disable/ object in render'

Tags: animation

[image]

For example, I want to make object appear from keyframe number 100 to keyframe number 200. And I don't want to see that object on 3D viewport and in render too. I already know the way clicking 'disable object in render' in Outliner menu. But that doesn't work on 3D viewport, so I want to know other way.

Answer (score 1):

Keyframes can be added for the visibility settings. Select the object and open the *Object* tab. In the *Visibility* panel you can adjust the settings and insert a keyframe either through the context menu or by pressing <kbd>I</kbd>.

For your specific problem, you could insert a keyframe at frame 0 with *Show in Viewports* and *Show in Render* disabled, then a keyframe at frame 100 with *Show in Viewports* and *Show in Render* enabled, followed by a keyframe at 201 with both disabled again.

[image: Visibility settinsg]

Comment: Thank you for answer, I understood it. But 'Visibility' isn't in Object tab..

Comment: If you have an object selected you should see the tab with orange square icon as depicted in the screenshot above. That is the object tab and should contain the *Visibility* panel.

Comment: There are Montion Paths, and Viewport Display penals. But there isn't Visiblity panel between them. Is it better to make another question for this?

Comment: Yes it's better to make a new question and please add a complete screenshot.

Comment: Okay, will do. Thank you

Comment: (If someone who are using alpha or beta version blender, install 2.8 released recently. [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/157234/how-can-i-find-visibility-panel-in-object-tab?noredirect=1#comment266647_157234))

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this, and I'm not sure if there are any "best practices" or generally recognized ideal ways of doing so. Here are two simple ones, though:

***Approach 1: Scale 0 to Finite Scale in 1 Frame***

Keyframe the object's X, Y, and Z scales as 0 when you don't want the object to appear:

[image]

And at some desired finite, positive scale when you do want it to appear:

[image]

Be careful to ensure that the transition from 0-scale to finite-scale happens within a single frame if you really want it to look like the object appearing/disappearing instantaneously.

That's it. Click play/render your animation.

***Approach 2: Keyframing Alpha Channels in Nodes***

I'll assume use of the Eevee Renderer for this example, but you can do something similar (with a few modifications) in Cycles. Suppose we want a simple blue sphere to appear on frame 50. One way to do this is to add this material to our sphere, key-framing (see yellow highlights) its mix shader to be fully transparent on frame 49:

[image]

And to be fully blue diffuse on frame 50:

[image]

Note that this only works as expected in Eevee when the material has its blend type set to a mode that will hide portions of the object which are transparent. (see red circle in images, where Alpha Clip is chosen, although Alpha Hashed and Alpha Blend will also work in this simple example)

Comment: I learned two simple solutions, thanks to you :)