# How can I find 'Visibility panel' in Object tab?

Tags: visibility

[image]

▲ I want to find Visibility panel in Object tab like the pic above.

[image]
▲ But I can't find it. Visibility panel is omitted.

How can I find Visiblitiy panel?

Comment: Are you using a alpha or beta version of Blender 2.80?

Comment: You're right. I was using beta version, and have solved the problem. I didn't think about it. Thank you very much! :)